# How to achieve a value of a multi-type message mesage?

Tags: ros, catkin, message, cmvision, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends,

I am trying to Subscribe from a topic, this topic has been published by CMVISION (/blobs) and has this type :

Header header
uint32 image_width
uint32 image_height
uint32 blob_count
Blob[] blobs

and in this type, "Blob" is another message type itself :
uint32 red
uint32 green
uint32 blue
uint32 area
uint32 x
uint32 y
uint32 left
uint32 right
uint32 top
uint32 bottom

I want to subscribe the "x" and "y" from this message, but I dont know hoe to call that,

For example I want to write them on the terminal  and in my "callback" function I wrote :

void callback1(const cmvision::Blobs::ConstPtr& msg1)
{

```
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", msg1->blobs ??????);
```

}

I tried to call that like an array, it didn't work.... can any body help me in this problem?

Thanks
HAmed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163061/how-to-achieve-a-value-of-a-multi-type-message-mesage-?/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

blobs should be a std::vector, so

```
msgl->blobs.at(i)
```

or

```
msgl->blobs[i]
```

should work

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1